# Raster not taking projection when converting from JP2 to TIFF using gdal.translate in Python

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2

I am converting a sentinel 2 image from .jp2 to .tiff. The conversion is okay but when I open the raster in QGIS it ask for me to set a CRS but when I check the metadata the CRS is already set to the CRS from the input file.

```
from osgeo import gdal

input="M:\\sentinel\\L1C_T33UUU_A036956_20220720T101819\\S2A_MSIL1C_20220720T101611_N0400_R065_T33UUU_20220720T140828.SAFE\\GRANULE\\L1C_T33UUU_A036956_20220720T101819\\IMG_DATA\\T33UUU_20220720T101611_B02.jp2"
output = "M:\\sentinel\\tiff\\band2.tiff"

dst_ds = gdal.Translate(input,output)
```

[image]

[image: gdal info from .jp2 file]

Comment: Please show what projection gdalinfo finds from the images.

Comment: So, in the TIFF file the corner coordinates are registered but not the coordinate reference system. Therefore QGIS is asking you to feed the CRS manually. Does gdalinfo find CRS from the .jp2 file?

Comment: What does `gdalinfo` report for the 10m subdataset? Find the subdataset name using `gdalinfo S2A_MSIL1C_20220720T101611_N0400_R065_T33UUU_20220720T140828.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml`

Comment: @user30184 yes it shows the CRS in the .jp2 file

Comment: So would you mind to add also that into your question? The text begins somehow like `Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",`

Comment: Gdalinfo looks good but I can have a closer look if you add the info as text instead of an image. As a workaround you can assign the CRS (EPSG:32633) manually.